# Cannot access tables in azure sql from android studio

Tags: android, sql-server, azure

this is my connection class to connect to the server

```
public class   ConnectionClass {

    @SuppressLint("NewApi")
    public static Connection CONN() {
        StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder()
                .permitAll().build();
        StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
        Connection conn = null;
        String ConnURL = null;
        try {


            Class.forName("net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver");
            conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://jazzitup.database.windows.net:1433;database=jazzitup.db;user=xxxxxxxx;password=xxxxxxxx;encrypt=true;trustServerCertificate=false;hostNameInCertificate=*.database.windows.net;loginTimeout=30");
            System.out.println("AZURE:"+conn);

        } catch (SQLException se) {
            Log.e("ERRO", se.getMessage());
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            Log.e("ERRO", e.getMessage());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("ERRO", e.getMessage());
        }
        return conn;
    }

 }
```

After this I called the CONN method and the connection is getting established.
but when I try to execute an insert opertion:

```
           Connection con = ConnectionClass.CONN();
            String query = "insert into user_table values ('" + profile.getId() + "','" + profile.getName() + "','" + profile.getProfilePictureUri(200,200).toString() + "')";
            PreparedStatement preparedStatement = con.prepareStatement(query);

                preparedStatement.executeUpdate();
```

I am getting SQLEXCEPTION 'user_table' is invalid object. Why is this happening?
[image: user_table exists in database and executes query in SQL Server Object Explorer]

Comment: Do you have any update?

Answer (score 0):

I have reproduced your issue on my site. After searching, I found that there is the statement from [jTDS FAQs](http://jtds.sourceforge.net/faq.html#urlFormat),

> The URL format for **jTDS** is:
>
> ```
> jdbc:jtds:<server_type>://<server>[:<port>][/<database>][;<property>=<value>[;...]]
> ```

As you can see that URL differs from [the connection URL of Microsoft JDBC Driver for SQL Server](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/jdbc/connection-url-sample). As a result, the database is not correctly specified, so it raises your issue. You could change your connection string to something like this:

```
jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://jazzitup.database.windows.net:1433/jazzitup.db;user=xxxxxxxx;password=xxxxxxxx;encrypt=true;trustServerCertificate=false;hostNameInCertificate=*.database.windows.net;loginTimeout=30
```

I tested it, it should work.